# HTML video Tag range not working propery in Django

Tags: python, django

Am creating a small website, where Django returns a movie and the video Tags handles and play the movie.
The video Tag plays the movie but the video tag range or slider doesn't work. When i try to  move it, it immediately goes back to 0 and the movie restarts. I don't want that, all i want is to move the range and the movie skips according to the range or slider values. I tried this before in Flask it worked fine, but with Django it isn't.

Here is are my models

```
class Movies(models.Model):
    genre = models.ForeignKey(Genres, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name="movie_genre")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    movie_image = models.ImageField(upload_to="movie_images", blank=True)
    movie_path = models.FileField(upload_to="movie_path", blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_released = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="movie_like", blank=True)
    favorites = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="movie_favorites", blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Movies('{self.genre.name}, {self.name}','{self.author}', '{self.date_released}')"

    def total_likes(self):
        return self.likes.count()

    def total_favorites(self):
        return self.favorites.count()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('home')
```

Here are my views

```
@login_required
def show_movie_data(request, id):
    movie = get_object_or_404(Movies, id=id)
    if movie:
        stuff = get_object_or_404(Movies, id=id)
        total_likes = stuff.total_likes()
        liked = False
        is_favorite = False

        if stuff.favorites.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
            is_favorite = True

        
        if stuff.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
            liked = True

        context = {
            'movie':movie,
            'total_likes':total_likes,
            'liked': liked,
            'is_favorite': is_favorite,
        }
        return render(request, 'main/show_movie_data.html', context)
    else:
        messages.warning(request, 'Movie not found')
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
```

Here is the HTML

```
<video controls preload="auto" style="width: 100%; height: 650px;" poster="{{movie.movie_image.url}}">
    <source src="{{ movie.movie_path.url }}" type="video/mp4">

</video>
```

Am not using any JavaScript for this. I don't know why this is happening but if anyone knows, am open for answers

Comment: 1. Check fror browser console if you are getting any error
2. Also please check if your clicking on control is not reloading the template again, its possible if your outer template code hitting the api again

Comment: There is no error in the console and the template doesn't reload

Comment: May be the problem is with the web browser because i tried to run the code in Opera and  Firefox. And the code worked fine in Firefox but in opera and Chrome, the range doesn't move